# How to set up Tomcat server with JSP Servlet Login

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets

I'm attempting to make a user on my site login with the right credentials before being able to access my webpage, so I created a simple servlet login to accomplish this. Inside of my web project in Eclipse it works perfectly, but when I try and run this on my Amazon ec2 instance and enter the credentials I get this error: `The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists.`I think it has to do with the configuration of my LoginCheck Java class and my web.xml file, because before I added the servlet login my site worked. Any suggestions?

index.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
        <title>AWS Ads Updater</title>
    </head> 
    <body>

         <form method="post" action="LoginCheck">
             <table>
                 <tr><td>Username</td><td><input type="text" name="uname"></td></tr>
                 <tr><td>Password</td><td><input type="password" name="password"></td></tr>
                 <tr><td></td><td><input type="submit" name="login"></td></tr>

            </table>
        </form>

    </body>
</html>
```

LoginCheck.java

```
    package LoginCheck.servlet;

import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class LoginCheck
 */
@WebServlet("/LoginCheck")
public class LoginCheck extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
     */
    public LoginCheck() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        response.getWriter().append("Served at: ").append(request.getContextPath());
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        String uname = request.getParameter("uname");
        String pass = request.getParameter("password");

        if(uname.equals("user") && pass.equals("pass")) {
            response.sendRedirect("LoginWorked.jsp");
        } else {
            response.sendRedirect("LoginFailed.jsp");
        }

    }

}
```

LoginWorked.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
       <meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
       <title>AWS Ads Updater</title>
    </head> 
    <body>
         <p>Login worked</p>
     </body>
</html>
```

LoginFailed.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
        <title>AWS Ads Updater</title>
    </head> 
    <body>
        <p>Login failed, please try again</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

web.XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1">
  <display-name>LoginCheck</display-name>    
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

Answer (score 0):

You had used a servlet but you could use a simple class java and you declare into jsp page your logic but this is only my idea.

I think that the problem is the `response.sendRedirect("LoginWorked.jsp");`, I have always used an object RequestDispatcher to redirect the request to another servlet.
The pages jsp are servlet into your case you have a three servlet

1. LoginCheck.java
2. LoginFailed_jsp.java
3. LoginWorked_jsp.java

Try using an object RequestDispatcher because your configuration seems correct

```
RequestDispatcher requestDispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("/LoginFailed.jsp");
try {
   requestDispatcher.forward(request, response);
} catch (ServletException ex) {
  ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't figure out this specific problem, but I found a workaround that accomplished what I wanted to do. Take a look at this link if you want to see how I was able to fix it: https://jelastic.com/blog/restrict-access-tomcat-web-application-hosting/

Answer (score -1):

I hate to fall into the SO stereotype of trashing your tech choices, but JSP are very outdated. IF you have the option, I'd recommend some newer technologies, like REST APIs with a javascript front-end over jsp. Look into jackson+jersey for java APIs and Angular/React/Vue.js for front end framework. You can also use Spring security for auth, and not have to run a servlet parallel with your webserver at all!

Nothing I said was untrue. [JSP has been deprecated by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/giepx.html) for years and we shouldn't be perpetuating it by creating new sites that use the tech. Plus, unless OP needs it for a specific job, they could better spend their time learning more commonly used technologies.

Comment: You probably got downvoted because this doesn't even attempt to answer the question. If you just want to provide info it should be a comment.

Comment: Also why would you recommend adding a JavaScript framework to the front end when you can add something like thymeleaf and bind your model directly to your front end template on th server?  It seems completely unnecessary.  most Java rest frameworks design controller functionality the same whether it's a rest endpoint or a servlet

Comment: The real problem with deprecating JSPs was that JSF/Facelets are quite complicated and tedious to work with, rely on XML (I wish xalan/xerces/xmlApis would die already), etc.  JSPs were a quick way to get java logic to help generate UI when a JS framework is not yet used.  Deprecation was unfortunate.  There are other templating frameworks, but all lack the ability to quickly get a page up.  Just a counterpoint.